# How to exclude conf files when do package using maven

Tags: maven

I have a project which will been used by other projects and when I package it, it always include the configuration files (beans.xml). I just want to exclude these configuration files. How can I do this ? Thanks

Comment: If the configuration file belongs to the other project the configuration should be moved to that project instead in your current.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your beans.xml is only part of your tests; you can put it in `src/test/resources`. It will not be added to the generated library.